# fedora 17 keyboard messed up in virtual box vdi

Tags: virtualbox, fedora-17

I just downloaded and installed the fedora 17 vdi file from http://virtualboxes.org/images/fedora/
and created a virtal os on my computer. I found that the keyboard was messed up. All of the non alpha-numeric (except for the . and ,) were not as they should be (some were just switched, the / was a -, but some were non American letters (such as the e with a mark over it.).

How can I fix this? Is it a virtual box problem or a fedora linix problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to reset the keyboard language (it seems it was in Italian). I did this by using the command 
     system-config-keyboard
which I found at this site:
 http://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions